# Find and replace '\' in vim

Tags: vim, neovim

I am trying to replace `D(t` by `\zb(t` using the following vim command

```
:s%|D(t|\zb(t,|g
```

but I get

```
Unknown operator '\zb'
```

How can I replace string with `\` inside or replace strings with other strings that have a `\` inside?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvim%5D+escape+backslash

Comment: Escape (screen) backslash using backslash because backslash is the escaping (screening) character: \\